# "/bin/bash cd ~" results in "/bin/bash: cd: No such file or directory", why?

Tags: linux, bash

The question is in the title. I could not find anything on google, so im hoping someone here can explain this to me.

I am using debian 6.0.5 and the shell assigned to the executing user in the /etc/passwd file is /bin/bash

So, simply writing `cd ~` works and brings me to the users home directory.

`test -d "~/some_dir"` returns false in an if statement ( some_dir exsits )

Edit:
Sorry I should've been more clear as of why I was writing `/bin/bash cd ~` instead of `cd ~`: I am writing a bash script with `#!/bin/bash` and the above mentioned if statement ends up in the false clause.

Comment: Perhaps this belongs at [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I don't get your edit, why don't you just test for the directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options for any command line are expanded before the command is run, even for internal commands.  Whatever shell you're using to run `/bin/bash cd ~` is presumably interpreting the tilde literally rather than a special character that expands to your home directory.

As a test, try creating a directory by that name and see if the error goes away.

```
> mkdir ./~
> /bin/bash cd ~
```

Note that the `cd` command needs to be done *within your running shell* to be useful.  When you change the working directory of a sub-shell, and then the sub-shell exits, you'll find yourself back where you started.

**UPDATE**:

From within a bash script, you should be able to use the `$HOME` environment variable, which should consistently contain your home directory.  I'm not aware what conditions would cause tilde expansion to fail, but I've always used `$HOME`.

Also, when determining whether you can change into a particular directory, you have the option of being explicit and returning useful status:

```
unset err
if [[ ! -d "$somedir" ]]; then
  err="Can't find $somedir"
elif [[ ! -r "$somedir" ]]; then
  err="Can't read $somedir"
fi

if [[ -n "$err" ]]; then
  echo "$ERROR: $err" >&2
  exit 1
fi

cd "$somedir"
```

Or, you can just try the CD and look at its results.

```
if ! cd "$somedir"; then
  echo "ERROR: $somedir not availble"
  exit 1
fi
```

Detailed error reports are handy, but if you don't need them, keeping your code small has advantages as well.

Comment: Replacing ~ with $HOME is a good enough solution for me, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
/bin/bash -c "cd ~"
```

Comment: what about `cd $HOME`? $HOME is the same than ~ I think

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you did

```
$ /bin/bash cd ~
```

your shell interpreted `cd` as an argument to `/bin/bash`. That syntax can e.g. be used to invoke shell scripts.

What you most likely wanted was to change the current working directory. In that case all you need is

```
$ cd ~
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use quotes `""`
Example:

```
$ test -d ~/.aptitude
$ echo $?
0
$ test -d "~/.aptitude"
$ echo $?
1
```

`~` is not expanded within the quotes `""`. Use `$HOME`

Comment: +1 I was just bit by this. I guess my script is getting complex enough it should be in Python...

Answer (score 0):

If you've set `$CDPATH`, you'll run into this issue.

Try `CDPATH=""` before your command. Also, you can add `.` to your $CDPATH:

`export CDPATH=.:/path/to/anywhere`